# MacOS: yeoman: command not found

Tags: angularjs, node.js, macos, bash

I know that there are many other questions towards this topic. But none of the answers helped for me :(

I simply want to do some AngularJS development using Yeoman. So here's what I did (on MacOS Yosemite):

1. installed Node.JS by downloading the PKG from the website
2. installed Yeoman by this command line `npm install -g yo grunt-cli bower`

When I then type `yeoman` or `yo` in the terminal, then I get `-bash: yeoman: command not found` error.

NodeJS is installed in `/usr/local/bin/node`
NPM is installed in `/usr/local/bin/npm`

Following other postings, I tried to change my $PATH variable but still did not work.

```
echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin/npm:/usr/local/bin/npm/bin:/usr/texbin:/Users/mheise/.node/bin

echo $NODE_PATH   (empty)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: It should be enough to use: "npm install -g yo"
Maybe you need to be sudo mode sometime.

Comment: It seems that `yo` is not symlinked in the `bin` folder. Usually `npm` does that when you install with `-g` flag, but it's worth a manual check.

Comment: In which bin folder should the symlink be located? And where should it point to? Just found out that npm and node are also not in /usr/local/bin even though the installation told me so. I also tried "npm install -g yo" but still both commands for yo and yeoman do not work.